# C# Telnet ANSI convert

Tags: c#, converters, telnet, ansi-escape

i have a TelnetConnection to a Server and I show the log on my Screen.
And it looks always so:

```
Test1   [ [91mERROR[0m ]
Test2   [  [92mOK[0m  ]
Test3   [  [92mOK[0m  ]
Overall [[91mERROR[0m ]
```

I think that is ANSI. How can I convert it?
Thank you in advance!

Homeros

My Code:

```
public string Read()
{
    if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        ParseTelnet(sb);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
    } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
    sb.ToString();
    return sb.ToString();
}

public bool IsConnected
{
    get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
}

void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
{
    while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
        switch (input)
        {
            case -1:
                break;
            case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                // interpret as command
                int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                if (inputverb == -1) break;
                switch (inputverb)
                {
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                        //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                        sb.Append(inputverb);
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.DO:
                    case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                    case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                    case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                        // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                        int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputoption == -1) break;
                        tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                        if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA)
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL : (byte)Verbs.DO);
                        else
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT);
                        tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append((char)input);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are ANSI control codes for a terminal, the change the color of the displayed text.  You can't really "translate" a color.  You don't have much use for StringBuilder, if you want to display colors then you need a RichTextBox or a WebBrowser control.  And a bunch of code that interprets these escape sequences.  Or go shopping, this has been done before, google "windows forms telnet control".  Lots of good looking hits.